# Populate list item from XML feed

Tags: list, splistitem, xml

How to create new list item using data from XML feed? Is it possible to handle multi line of text in XML feed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the full context of your data, but the way I see you either, create the actual list instance as part of your SharePoint solution where you could use

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <ListInstance Title="ListWithXml"                
                    TemplateType="10001"
                    Url="Lists/MyListName"
                    Description="This list gets default data">
        <Data>
          <Rows>
            <Row>
              <Field Name="Title">Title Item 01</Field>
              <Field Name="Notes">Lorem Ipsum dolor sitament....</Field>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Field Name="Title">Title Item 02</Field>
              <Field Name="Notes">Long field with content from long field</Field>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Field Name="Title">T</Field>
            </Row>
          </Rows>
        </Data>    
      </ListInstance>
    </Elements>
```

1. Rely on some Event Receiver (eg. ListAdded event - see more
   explanations
   http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-theory/)
   to read data from the XML upon List creation - via SharePoin
   Server-Side Object model
2. Use any Client Side Object model to fill-in the list yourself, via
   some kind of Console Application. - If all depends on the structure of your XML, because you need to handle the actual mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 (Simplest):Just open the File with excel (File->Open choose xml) and paste to sharepoint list(data sheet view)

Solution 2 : Parse the xml yourself...